# Text losing style (even though css shows it should have it), but not if code is stepped through on console (jsfiddles included)

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

(I have only confirmed this to happen so far with Safari 12.1.2 on MacOS Mojave)

So I have a contenteditable div with a styled span (red) and some text inside it. Nothing weird yet.

However, when I do some operations on the text (keeping all the text still **within the same styled span**) some of the text loses its style even though inspecting the DOM shows it should be styled (red).

> Here's a jsfiddle illustrating the issue above:
>
> ## 1: https://jsfiddle.net/tx71pqmv/5/

```
$('#editable').keypress((event) => {
    if (event.key != 'Enter' || !event.shiftKey)
        return;
    event.preventDefault()
    let sel = window.getSelection()
    let range = sel.getRangeAt(0)
    let newLine = $('<span>')
        .addClass('br')
        .attr('contenteditable', 'false')[0]
    range.startContainer.splitText(range.startOffset) // 1
    range.insertNode(newLine) // 2
})
```

[image: Example of unintended effect]

The weird thing is that this issue happens under VERY specific conditions.

For example, if I step through the code using the debugger, or use setTimeout to delay the execution by even 1ms ([see jsfiddle #2](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbxkvodh/10/)), then everything works as intended.

Or, even just getting rid of the ::before pseudo-element on the containing div (not even the styled span) fixes the issue ([see jsfiddle #3](https://jsfiddle.net/58091guj/2/)). This should be totally unrelated!

Is there a cleaner solution to the problem that doesn't involve compromising on the css or using setTimeout?

Edit: Adding screenshots of the DOM structure after pressing shift+enter on the first jsfiddle, and the second. The DOM structure on both look identical, but the one on the right doesn't have styling applied to one of the text nodes:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here `shift+Enter` and `Enter` behaving differently for the `#editable` div

- `Enter` is creating a new child (`div`) of `#editable` div 
  means you have more child every time you press shift enter
- but `Shift + Enter` is creating new line inside the `child div > span`

browsers behave differently for `contenteditables`

as MDN says

```
Use of contenteditable across different browsers has been painful for a long time because of the differences in generated markup between browsers.
```

Read this for more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

new div created using `enter`

[image: new div created using <code>enter</code>]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm fairly sure the event.preventDefault() prevents shift+enter from creating a new contenteditable div. Indeed, you can see for yourself in the jsfiddle, by inspecting the elements after shift+enter is pressed – there will only be one div. 

Pressing enter just by itself will, as you said, create a new div, but that is not relevant to the issue (I'm fairly sure)

Comment: I tested your fiddle on safari to confirming the new div is created on `shift+enter`.

Comment: I added screenshots to the answer showing the DOM structure I get after pressing shift+enter and there is only 1 div for me. Chrome does not create a new div, either, but it does not have the issue I described (all the text remains red).

Comment: ok, I see the bug now, if you use the `div` instead of `span.some-class` it works fine for some reason, updating my answer

Comment: also its the opposite , `enter` creates new div

Comment: You're right, using a div works. Unfortunately, adding display: inline to the div to make it behave like a span (which is what I want) makes the bug reappear. 
See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d7auL0os/

Comment: Also shift+enter by default creates a newline inside of the same div, but since I am using preventDefault() to override the behavior, no newline is actually created (by the browser atleast). 

The span that is inserted into the range (class br) has display:block so it behaves like a br (I did this as an attempt to standardize shift+enter functionality across browsers)